# How to hide print preview page in web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I want to hide print preview page . Actually i want when i click the print button, page printing should be started without showing print preview .

I am Using following code .

HTML :-

```
<form id="form1">
    <div id="dvContainer">
        This content needs to be printed.
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Print Div Contents" id="btnPrint" />
</form>
```

JQuery :-

```
<script>
    $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
            var divContents = $("#dvContainer").html();
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        });
</script>
```

If it is possible to hide print preview  page , So please Help me out .

And i have also created a fiddle [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/as88425/wsg1orvp/)

Comment: JavaScript can't force the browser to print without the user seeing the print dialog. (For good reason: just imagine how obnoxious some web pages could be if they *could* force printing to start immediately.)

Comment: It's not a possible.

Comment: Hey @nnnnnn if my print is printing well what i want after that if i hide the printpeeview . Actually i wanna to do for a ofline project there is no access of users .